# Connecting Orchard Core with a user management

Tags: orchardcms, user-management

Is it possible to connect an orchard core app to an already existing user management app? I'd like to login in the orchard core app but verify the user and check it's role in an already existing user management and according to what the user management returns, I want to show the corresponding content for that user in the orchard core app. Anyone knows if anything like this has been done?